# Reading the content from an inputstream using scanner multiple times is not behaving as expected

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I am using the following code to read content from an input stream.

```
@Test
public void testGetStreamContent(){
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello World!!".getBytes());
        System.out.println(getStreamContent(is));
        System.out.println("Printed once");
        System.out.println(getStreamContent(is));
}

public static String getStreamContent(InputStream is) {
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(is);
        s.useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    } finally {
        if (s != null){
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the output to contain Hello World!! twice, but it is not returning the text the second time. Following is the only output.

```
Hello World!!
Printed once
```

I have tried resetting the scanner by using s.reset(). But that is also not working.

Comment: Generally, you can't use an `InputStream` twice, you must create a new `ByteArrayInputStream` every time you need to call `getStreamContent()`

Comment: You've already scanned the input stream to its end. It doesn't magically rewind itself.

Comment: Yeah. I see that now. I tried is.reset() and it worked. I think I can delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello World!!".getBytes());
    if(is.markSupported()){
        is.mark("Hello World!!".length());
    }
    System.out.println(getStreamContent(is));
    is.reset();
    System.out.println("Printed once");
    System.out.println(getStreamContent(is));
```

Things to note:  I changed the variable type from `InputStream` to the instance type so I could call the methods specific to that type (`mark`, `reset` and `markSupported` ).  That allows the stream to point back to the last marked position.

Comment: Yes, I figured out the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a reset on inputstream is working for me.

```
public static String getStreamContent(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    if(is == null)
        return "";
    is.reset();
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(is);
        s.reset();
        s.useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    } finally {
        if (s != null){
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```